# How does this Sample AngularJS Infinite Scroll work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have found this sample AngularJS script when I was searching for some, but then I can't seem to get my head around the angular module and directive part of the code. Though I have managed to edit the loadMore() function to retrieve a json resource from my ReSTful API and it works great with the infinite scroll, can someone please give an explanation on how this works, I would really appreciate it. I have just barely started reading and trying AngularJS for the past week during my spare time...

Original from fiddle (A BIG Thank You to the original Author): http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/

```
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];

    var counter = 0;
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $scope.items.push({id: counter});
            counter += 10;
        }
    };

    $scope.loadMore();
}

angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];

        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Modified by me:

```
function Main($scope, $http) {

    $scope.phones = [];

    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        $http.get('http://www.somewhere.com/api/phones').success(function(data) {
            if($scope.phones.length > 0) {
                $scope.phones = $scope.phones.concat(data);
            }
            else {
                $scope.phones = data;
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.loadMore();
}
```

Comment: which part/code is most unclear to you?

Comment: The whole angular.module whenScrolled directive bit. How the infinite scroll works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll have a go at this:

This directive returns a link function, which will be called for each instance of the directive. So it will get executed on load and attach an on scroll event handler to each list item. If the height calculation is true then it will attach an attribute "whenScrolled", which is a directive to the current li and force Angular to recompile the DOM, which will process the new directive, and this directive will call loadMore(), adding more items to the list.

The apply is needed because Angular will not process the newly added directive on the list item and our on scroll handler will not be added.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your explanation was clear to me and I'm almost there. But can you please also try to explain the parameters found on the return function (scope, elm, attr) and what it's for, how it was used.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as you have explained it the way I understand and also helped me to look at the right direction. Thanks